# Is there anyway I can use preemptible instance for dataflow jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

It's evident that preemptible instance are cheaper than non-preemptible instance. On daily basis 400-500 dataflow jobs are running in my organisational project. Out of which some jobs are time-sensitive and others are not. So is there any way I could use preemptible instance for non-time-constraint job, which will cost me less for overall pipeline execution. Currently I'm running dataflow jobs with below specified configuration.

```
        options.setTempLocation("gs://temp/");
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
        options.setTemplateLocation("gs://temp-location/");
        options.setWorkerMachineType("n1-standard-4");
        options.setMaxNumWorkers(20);
        options.setWorkerCacheMb(2000);
```

I'm not able to find out any pipeline options with preemptible instance setting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do so with **Flexible Resource Scheduling** in Cloud Dataflow ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/flexrs)). Note that there are some things to consider:

- **Delayed execution**: jobs are scheduled and not executed right away (you can see a new `QUEUED` [status](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#Status) for your Dataflow jobs). They are run opportunistically when resources are available within a **six-hour window**. This makes FlexRS suitable to reduce cost for **non-time-critical workloads**. Also, be sure to validate your code before sending the job.
- **Batch jobs**: as of now it only accepts batch jobs and requires to enable **autoscaling**:

  > You cannot set autoscalingAlgorithm=NONE
- **Dataflow Shuffle**: it needs to be **enabled**. When so, no data is stored on persistent disks attached to the VMs. This way, when a preemption happens and resources are claimed back there is no need to redistribute the data.
- **Regions**: according to the previous item, only regions **where Dataflow Shuffle is supported** can be selected. List [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#cloud-dataflow-shuffle), turn-up for new regions will be announced in the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/release-notes-service). As of now, zone is automatically chosen within the region.
- **Machine types**: FlexRS currently supports **`n1-standard-2`** (default) and **`n1-highmem-16`**.
- **SDK**: requires **2.12.0** or newer for Java or Python.
- **Quota**: quota is reserved upfront (i.e. **queued jobs** also consume quota).

In order to **run** it, use **`--flexRSGoal=COST_OPTIMIZED`** and make sure to take into account that the rest of parameters conform to the FlexRS needs.

A **uniform discount rate** is applied to FlexRS jobs, you can compare pricing details in the [following link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing#pricing_details).

Note that you might see a Beta disclaimer in the non-English documentation but, as clarified in the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/release-notes-service#November_18_2019), it's **Generally Available.**

Comment: Could you please upvote the question, so that others can refer to this.

Comment: Hey @miles212 how did you add FlexRS as a parameter. Can you describe the changes that you did to make it work?